# NASM addition program

Tags: linux, nasm

I am a developer who uses high level languages, learning assembly language in my spare time.  Please see the NASM program below:

```
section .data

section .bss

section .text
global main
main:
    mov eax,21
    mov ebx,9
    add eax,ebx
    mov ecx,eax
    mov eax,4
    mov ebx,1
    mov edx,4
    int 0x80
push ebp
mov ebp,esp

mov esp,ebp
pop ebp
ret
```

Here are the commands I use:

ian@ubuntu:~/Desktop/NASM/Program4$ nasm -f elf -o asm.o SystemCalls.asm
ian@ubuntu:~/Desktop/NASM/Program4$ gcc -o program asm.o
ian@ubuntu:~/Desktop/NASM/Program4$ ./program

I don't get any errors, however nothing is printed to the terminal.  I used the following link to ensure the registers contained the correct values: http://docs.cs.up.ac.za/programming/asm/derick_tut/syscalls.html

Comment: `sys_call` writes strings, not integers. It expects a string pointer in `ecx`, but you're giving it the value `30`.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to convert the integer value to a string to be able to print it with `sys_write` (syscall 4). The conversion could be done like this (untested):

```
; Converts the integer value in EAX to a string in
; decimal representation.
; Returns a pointer to the resulting string in EAX.
int_to_string:
  mov byte [buffer+9],0  ; add a string terminator at the end of the buffer
  lea esi,[buffer+9]
  mov ebx,10             ; divisor      
int_to_string_loop:
  xor edx,edx            ; clear edx prior to dividing edx:eax by ebx
  div ebx                ; EAX /= 10
  add dl,'0'             ; take the remainder of the division and convert it from 0..9 -> '0'..'9'
  dec esi                ; store it in the buffer
  mov [esi],dl
  test eax,eax
  jnz int_to_string_loop    ; repeat until EAX==0
  mov eax,esi
  ret

buffer: resb 10
```

Comment: Thanks +1.  Is there any documentation explaining the information in the 'name' column of my link e.g. explaining what sys_exit is?

Comment: [This page](http://asm.sourceforge.net/syscall.html) has brief descriptions of what the system calls do.

Comment: Thanks.  Last question.  Do you always have to convert to a string if you want to print to the page?

Comment: Normally you'd just use `printf`, which handles all the conversions for you. But if you want to use system calls I don't think there's any way around doing the int-to-string conversion.

Comment: Last question (I promise).  If you have a statement: msg db "Hello",10,0.  What is meant by: 10,0?

Comment: 10 is the [ascii code](http://www.asciitable.com/) for the linefeed "character", and the 0 is used as a string terminator in most implementations (one exception being DOS, which used `'$'` as the string terminator for many of its functions).

Comment: 0 in ASCII is null. How can this be a terminator?

Comment: _Any_ character can potentially be a terminator, but 0 (NUL) is the most common one. The character NUL and a NULL _pointer_ are not the same thing, if that's what you were worried about.

Comment: Thanks.  What is the null character? Is it a blank space?

Comment: You don't print the NUL character. It's only used to determine where the string ends.

Answer (score 0):

programming in assembly requires a knowledge of ASCII codes and a some basic conversion routines. example: hexadecimal to decimal, decimal to hexadecimal are good routines to keep somewhere on some storage.
No registers can be printed as they are, you have to convert (a lot).
To be a bit more helpfull:
ASCII 0 prints nothing but some text editors (kate in kde linux) will show something on screen (a square or ...). In higher level language like C and C++ is it used to indicate NULL pointers and end of strings.
Usefull to calculate string lengths too.
10 is end of line. depending Linux or Windows there will be a carriage return (Linux) too or not (Windows/Dos).
13 is carriage return
1B is the ESC key (Linux users will now more about this)
255 is a hard return, I never knew why it is good for but it must have its purpose.
check http://www.asciitable.com/ for the entire list.

Answer (score -1):

Convert the integer value to a string.
Here i have used macros pack and unpack to convert integers to string and macro unpack to do the vice-versa

```
%macro write 2 
    mov   eax, 4
    mov   ebx, 1
    mov   ecx, %1
    mov   edx, %2
    int   80h
%endmacro

%macro read 2 
    mov eax,3
    mov ebx,0
    mov ecx,%1
    mov edx,%2
    int 80h
%endmacro


%macro pack 3   ;    1-> string ,2->length ,3->variable
    mov esi, %1
    mov ebx,0
    %%l1:
    cmp byte [esi], 10
    je %%exit

    imul ebx,10
    movzx edx,byte [esi]
    sub edx,'0'
    add ebx,edx
    inc esi
    jmp %%l1
    %%exit:
    mov  [%3],ebx
%endmacro

%macro unpack 3    ; 1-> string ,2->length ,3->variable
    mov esi, %1
    mov ebx,0
    movzx eax, byte[%3]
    mov byte[%2],0

    cmp eax, 0
    jne %%l1
    mov byte[%2],1
    push eax
    jmp %%exit2

    %%l1:
    mov ecx,10
    mov edx,0
    div ecx
    add edx,'0'
    push edx
    inc byte[%2]
    cmp eax, 0
    je %%exit2

    jmp %%l1 

    %%exit2:
    movzx ecx,byte[%2]
    %%l2:
    pop edx
    mov [esi],dl
    inc esi
    loop %%l2
%endmacro

section .data       ; data section
msg1:   db "First number : "    ; 
len1:   equ $-msg1      ; 
msg2:   db "Second number : "   ; 
len2:   equ $-msg2      ;                   
msg3:   db "Sum : " ; 
len3:   equ $-msg3      ;   
ln: db 10
lnl: equ $-ln
var1: resb 10
var2: resb 10
str1: resb 10
str2: resb 10
ans: resb 10
ansvar: resb 10
ansl: db ''
l1: db ''
l2: db ''

section.text        ;code
global _start
_start:
    write msg1,len1
    read str1,10      
    pack str1,l1,var1

    write msg2,len2
    read str2,10      
    pack str2,l2,var2    

    mov al,[var1]
    add al,[var2]

    mov [ansvar],al
    unpack ans,ansl,ansvar
    write msg3,len3
    write ans,10
    write ln,lnl

    mov ebx,0       ; exit code, 0=normal
    mov eax,1       ; exit command to kernel
    int 0x80        ; interrupt 80 hex, call kernel
```

To assembler, link and run:

```
nasm -f elf add.asm 
ld -s -o add add.o
./add
```

Comment: execution: nasm -f elf add.asm (say); ld -s -o add add.o ; ./add

Comment: Pack and unpack are ambiguous names. Had you considered being a tad more descriptive with the macro names so the code is readable? I had to actually read the macro code to know what was going on. There is no description of the macros, vague usage information etc. This is more or less a code dump with no explanation. I'd also point out that the code in your example is GAS and the OP was asking about NASM.